# Set Final Price by javascript (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, javascript

I'm playing with some calculations and everything seems ok visually, I could get the price from:

```
<span class="price">$280.98</span>
```

And use in my formula, however, I want to change the final price that goes to shopping cart.

Because in my case I can handle everything visually via javascript but when I press Add to Cart button, the amount that goes to shopping cart is not the one I have changed on the tag.

Is there a javascript code that I can reset the final price?

Comment: Its because of you are displayed updated price by JS, But it back end Magento still using the same/old price. You need to set your quote product price by Magento way.

Comment: Well... I know there is a way to reset the price by JS. I saw some plugins doing that before. I just don't know how they set.